# If statement inside a while loop doesn't work and i don't know why

Tags: java

I'm working in a little game project in Java and I got a weird problem: I have a Runnable class, and in the run(), an if condition doesn't work if it doesn't have a println() before

It work like this:

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Run");
    while(running){
        System.out.println(""); // this print is "important"
        if (KeyManager.isDown(KeyManager.A)){
            bulletC.addBullet(new Bullet()); //this works
        }
    }
}
```

but not like this:

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Run");
    while(running){
        //System.out.println(""); //no print
        if (KeyManager.isDown(KeyManager.A)){
            bulletC.addBullet(new Bullet()); //this doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working in NetBeans 8.2 and I've tried closing and opening the project again, recompiling, cleaning, restarting the IDE but nothing seems to work, ideas?

The point of all this is that the if statement works without needing the print()

Edit:
Here is the code where run() is called

```
    @Override
    public void init() {
        tileMap = new TileMap(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        tileMap.loadMap();
        player = new Player(tileMap);
        bulletC = new BulletController(1);

        setCamera();

        Runnable runnable = this;
        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start(); // here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work?  What happens when you debug and when pressing the button?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the buffer not being flushed.

Comment: what is the use of `System.out.println("Run");` and how and where have you set the variable `running`

Comment: I'm just using that print as a flag for the run() method, i got "run" in the output

Comment: I mean that the `bulletC.add()` it's not being execute, but with the "print", it does

Comment: what happens when you remove the line `System.out.println("Run");` and run your program? I means without `System.out.println("Run");` and `System.out.println("");`

Comment: I'm using a Game State Machine and the value for `running` is basically always `true` (an infinite loop). I tried putting "true" directly but nothing

Comment: did you try what I had suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: If i remove both print() doesn't work either, this is weird

Comment: could you post some of the related code like how you are calling run?

Comment: Looks like a race condition in the code. Learn about parallel programming and synchronization of threads.

Comment: Thanks Henry, you were right! I didn't know about it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henry, you were right dude, you saved me!
It was a thread synchronization problem, sychronized() was missing:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    while(running){
        synchronized(bulletC){
        if (KeyManager.isDown(KeyManager.A)){
                bulletC.addBullet(new Bullet());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the support!